# Completing the missing rows when outer joining to a table of counts

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with an OUTER JOIN not providing enough empty rows.

The business context is users starting (and hopefully finishing) online tests. Each user can attempt each test multiple times.

I am trying to report on how many times each user has started/completed each test. In particular, for every user who has attempted at least one test, I would like to display a row of counts for each test (even the ones they haven't attempted at all).

The TEST table is very simple.

```
    ID  NAME
    --  ----
    1   Test 1
    2   Test 2
```

The PROGRESS table provides the counts for combinations of tests and users.

```
    TEST_ID  USER_ID  NUM_TIMES_STARTED  NUM_TIMES_FINISHED
    -------  -------- -----------------  ------------------
    1        Alice    2                  1
    1        Bob      1                  0
```

What I want to see is the following (the 2nd and 4th rows are the key ones):

```
    USER_ID  TEST_NAME  TIMES_STARTED  TIMES_FINISHED
    -------  ---------  -------------  --------------
    Alice    Test 1     2              1
    Alice    Test 2     0              0
    Bob      Test 1     1              0
    Bob      Test 2     0              0
```

My attempt to produce this is:

```
    SELECT p.user_id, t.name, COALESCE(p.num_times_started, 0), 
        COALESCE(p.num_times_finished, 0)
    FROM test t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN progress p
    ON t.id = p.test_id
    ORDER BY p.user_id, t.id
```

But this doesn't *repeat* the missing row for Test 2, once for each user - I just get one extra row back.

```
    USER_ID  TEST_NAME  TIMES_STARTED  TIMES_FINISHED
    -------  ---------  -------------  --------------
    Alice    Test 1     2              1
    Bob      Test 1     1              0
    (null)   Test 2     0              0
```

What I'm missing is how to apply the extra rows generated by the outer join at the agent level, rather than the whole data set...

(The database server is Oracle 9i. I am not able to make any changes to the table structure).

Thanks very much in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you ever upgrade this database to 10g or higher (hopefully higher, given the latest db version is 12.2!), then you could achieve your results by using a [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312), rather than having to faff around and cross join before doing another join and filtering etc etc

Comment: Thank you for the excellent link - simply adding PARTITION BY user_id has fixed my first attempt for Oracle 11. The client is hopefully upgrading this year...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross join in CTE, left join the data

```
with CTE as
(
select distinct user_id, test_name
from Progress
cross join test
)
select CTE.*, 
       COALESCE(p.num_times_started, 0), 
       COALESCE(p.num_times_finished, 0)
from CTE
left join progress p
  on p.user_id = CTE.user_ID
  and p.test_id = CTE.test_id
```

Comment: Thanks very much John - very neat and it gives just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just `CROSS JOIN` the distinct users who have taken a test:

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       t.test_name,
       COALESCE( p.num_times_started,  0 ) AS num_times_started,
       COALESCE( p.num_times_finished, 0 ) AS num_times_finished
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM progress ) u
       CROSS JOIN
       test t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN progress p
       ON ( u.user_id = p.user_id AND t.id = p.test_id )
```